# Python Selenium - dynamically generated data not added to DOM

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using python selenium

I am running this simple code

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
#Also use driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("my_url")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lb_LoadMore_button_text_2']").click()
print [x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//font[@class='ProductTitle']")]
```

The button I am clicking is a 'load more' button. On the Chrome webdriver I see that the items are being loaded, but I don't know how to access them after the click was committed.

I have also tried driver.refresh() before trying to print the elements

I am admittedly fresh to selenium and have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just need a delay after a click, but let's not just add a `time.sleep()` call, but [explicitly wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the product titles to be present via `presence_of_all_elements_located()`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='lb_LoadMore_button_text_2']").click()

# waiting
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
product_titles = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//font[@class='ProductTitle']")))

print [x.text for x in product_titles]
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I tried time.sleep but it did not sleep long enough. wait.until is better.